# Social buttons twitter facebook disappear when changing page with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, facebook-like, turbolinks

I'm using twitter and facebook social buttons without the need for SDKs or auths.

https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

When I first load the page or refresh, the tweet button and the share button show. But when I navigate via clicking links, the same social buttons don't show.

How do I get the scripts to load and play nice with turbolinks?

Comment: Was anyone able to figure this out? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to **turbolinks** not reloading your javascript on page reload. This is an expected behavior of turbolinks; however, sometimes you need to reload third-party javascript as in your case.

**Solution:**

Disable turbolinks on links leading to the page containing javascript you need to reload. In your case links that lead to pages with your social buttons.

**Example:**

```
<%= link_to "the page containing your social buttons", social_page_path, "data-no-turbolink": true %>
```

**Another Solution:**

If your social buttons are binded to the page realod event then you can force turbolinks to reload them everytime. Use the complementary gem [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) Follow the installation instruction and you can force turbolinks to reload all javascript you want inside document.ready() funciton.

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your social buttons javascript code
});
```

This way you don't have to manually disable turbolinks on links leading to pages containing your social buttons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can I have it on the page itself somehow, rather than having to manage all the links leading to that page?

Comment: Having it on the same page means that turbolinks already parsed the page! You have to tell turbolinks beforehand wither to fully reload the css and js resources or not. If it is really cumbersome to manually disable turbolinks on all links leading to this page, then turbolinks might not fit your application and you might consider disabling turbolinks altogether by removing it from your Gemfile.

Comment: Where do you have the javascript code for your social buttons?

Comment: the js code for the social buttons... it's an oauth integration gem, and there is an output snippet on the view template, but i'm not sure if the javascript is in my gem or code, or if it's just a blob returned by the social services (lol social services).

Comment: Try adding jquery-turbolinks to your gemfile, and let me know if it works.